# how to convert the string value of a reader in integer value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code to fetch the max value of s_no and then increment it by one.
but when the database has no value it will read null value and how do i check the null value and convert it into integer

```
cmd3 = New SqlCommand("select max(S_no) from dbo.place", con)
        dr1 = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
        If (IsNumeric(dr1.Read())) Then
            s_no = Integer.Parse(dr1.ToString()) + 1
        Else
```

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do with this code? If you are using this to decide the next S_no to use then be aware that this approach is very wrong in a multiuser environemt

Comment: You don't need a Reader in this case, those are for reading multiple columns/rows and you can't convert them straight to an integer. Instead, try using ExecuteScalar() which is used to return a single value, then you can cast its return into an integer

Comment: sir  i am trying to find the next serial no to use for table.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `ExecuteScalar` as suggested by soohoonigan in the comments but you can't just cast the result as type `Integer` because you'll still get `NULL` if there are no records.  With the SQL you have, you should do this:

```
Dim result = cmd3.ExecuteScalar()
Dim number = If(result Is DBNull.Value, 0, CInt(result))
```

That way, you'll get 0 if there are no records and incrementing it will give you 1 as the first value.

The alternative would be to change the SQL to return 0 if there are no records:

```sql
select isnull(max(S_no), 0) from dbo.place
```

and then you're guaranteed of `ExecuteScalar` returning an `Integer`:

```
Dim number = CInt(cmd3.ExecuteScalar())
```

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking.  Did you change your code as suggested?  Did it work?  If so, we're done.  If not, please edit your question and add the new code with the current behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a column is null with (here for column 0):

```
If dr1.IsDBNull(0) Then ...
```

If its not null you can then read the integer with

```
s_no = dr1.GetInt32(0)
```

---

If the query returns one row and one column, you can `ExecuteScalar` instead:

```
Dim result As Object = cmd3.ExecuteScalar()
If result Is DBNull.Value Then
    'HANDLE NULL
Else
    s_no = Convert.ToInt32(result)
End If
```